# Fill in Inkscape form and export it to PDF

Tags: python, elementtree, inkscape

I'm a beginner in programming and I would like to create a graphical interface with Qt in order to edit labels in PDF through the Inkscape software. In the graphical interface, I would like to be able to select a template among others that I will have previously created in Inkscape and fill in the fields to be filled in these templates to then export them in PDF format to be printed. I have tried to find out about automating tasks in Inkscape using Python but I haven't found many resources, has anyone looked into this and could they advise me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you can achieve that using at least two approaches: 1) since SVG is a text based format, you can fill the appropriate fields using some commands such as 'sed' or using an XML library in Python then use Inkscape to export the result to PDF: `inkscape document.svg --export-type=pdf --export-filename document.pdf`
2) You can search in the list of verbs/actions of Inkscape (run: `inkscape --action-list` or `inkscape --verb-list`) to see if there is a verb/action to fill the text, then use the command above to export to PDF.

Comment: The question is broad and needs more focus. Please ask about one specific, concrete problem at a time. Have you written any code at all?

Comment: There's an extension that does this: https://gitlab.com/Moini/nextgenerator - you could generate the CSV file with your graphical interface.